# Very odd Windows WiFi connection issue

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, troubleshooting

First time posting here, so sorry if things aren't in the usual format.

Issue: Working on a friend's laptop with WiFi issues. Laptop can connect to my WiFi network with no issues, but refuses to connect to hers. When I attempt to connect to her network, the connection window pops up with "Getting Information from $Network". It never gets to the point where it allows me to enter a password or anything.

Additional Info:

- Laptop connects to other WPA2 secured networks
- WiFi has plenty of signal

What I have tried so far:

- Reinstalled driver from Dell website
- Cleared all wireless networks from the stored networks list
- Cleared all references to $Network in the registry, multiple places
- Restarted multiple times
- Unable to test with Ubuntu as WiFi card is not supported on the live distro

Odd bit:

If I add the network manually in the remembered networking panel, it will connect fine.

It's as if there is some corrupted setting pertaining to $Network, but I can't find it anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same issue with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 AGN on Dell XPS L401X, Windows 7 x64. Ended up with rolling back the drivers. My current version is 13.3.0.24 dated 7/14/2010. Don't forget to disable respective update from Microsoft as it is available.

Comment: When you add the network manually are you assigning a static IP, etc?

Comment: Adding the network involves telling it the SSID, encryption, and security key. DHCP takes over for all of the LAN details.